# Docker zeppelin + Docker openresty

Tags: docker, apache-zeppelin, openresty

Am currently trying to put Nginx (Openresty version) in front of Apache Zeppelin - both are docker images. While I try to do this, for WebSocket, am getting 405 error. If I try to access WebSockets directly for Zeppelin, it works; but if I try to proxy the same using Openresty, it fails.

Please help with a solution. Thanks in Advance.

Below is the configuration file for nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log /dev/stderr warn;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

# make sure to set plaintext JWT_SECRET environment variable
env JWT_SECRET;

http {

    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /dev/stdout main;

    lua_package_path "/usr/local/openresty/lualib/?.lua;;";

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1;

    server {
        listen 80;

        server_name localhost:8080;

        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http') {
            return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        }

        location /zeppelin/ {
            proxy_pass ZEPPELIN_WEB_URL;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }

        location /zeppelin/ws {
            proxy_pass ZEPPELIN_WEBSOCKET_URL;
            proxy_pass_header Sec-Websocket-Extensions;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_read_timeout 86400;
        }

        location / {
            access_by_lua_file /bearer.lua;

            default_type text/html;

            proxy_pass PROXY_SERVER_NAME;

            proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";

            header_filter_by_lua_block {
                ngx.header.content_length = nil
            }

            body_filter_by_lua_block {
                if (ngx.req.get_headers()["Origin"] ~= nil) then
                    local response_body = ngx.arg[1]
                    local string_to_search = "</body>"
                    local replacement_string = "<script>document.domain = \"" .. ngx.req.get_headers()["Origin"] .. "\";</script></body>"
                    ngx.arg[1] = ngx.re.sub(ngx.arg[1], "</body>", replacement_string)
                end

                return ngx.arg[1]
            }
        }
    }
}
```